# What is the difference between these two List in Python?

Tags: python

I have two Lists in my program `list1` and `list2` which looks like the following:

```
list1 = ['ABC',
 'ABD',
 'ABE',
 'ABF',
 'ABG',
 'ABH',
 'ABI',
...]

list2 = [('A', 'B', 'C'),
 ('A', 'B', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'E'),
 ('A', 'B', 'F'),
 ('A', 'B', 'G'),
 ('A', 'B', 'I'),
...]
```

Both the Lists are 2D because they return the same result on the same operation.

```
list1[0][1] returns 'B'
list2[0][1] also returns 'B'
```

What is the difference between `list1` and `list2` if they return the same result? How do I convert `list2` in the format of `list1`?

Thank you.

Comment: `list1` is a list of strings while `list2` is a list of tuples.

strings and tuples are instances of `typing.Sequence` and support indexing

`list2tolist1 = [''.join(t) for t in list2]`

Comment: [type(x) for x in list1] and [type(x) for x in list2] is a good starting point.

Comment: Just to clear your misunderstanding up, those lists are *not* both 2D. The first list is 1-dimensional containing `str`s and the second list is 2-dimensional, with the first dimension being the `list` of `tuple`s and the second dimension being the `str`s inside those `tuple`s. The reason why your operations (indexing) gave the same result is that both `str`s and `tuple`s can be indexed in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first list is list of strings and second list is list of tuples containing strings.

To convert list2 to list1 you can use:

```
list2 = [('A', 'B', 'C'),
 ('A', 'B', 'D'),
 ('A', 'B', 'E'),
 ('A', 'B', 'F'),
 ('A', 'B', 'G'),
 ('A', 'B', 'I'),]
new_list = [''.join(v) for v in list2]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['ABC', 'ABD', 'ABE', 'ABF', 'ABG', 'ABI']
```